# TornadoFX overriding layoutChildren on Region

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

Im trying to translate [this](https://github.com/Apress/pro-javafx-8/blob/master/projavafx8/ch05/Reversi/src/projavafx/reversi/ui/ReversiSquare.java) JavaFX class to TornadoFX. Hover im not able to figure out how `protected void layoutChildren()` should be done with TornadoFX?

This is the code I have so far:

```
class ReversiSquare(x: Int, y: Int) : View() {

    var x by property(x)
    fun xProperty() = getProperty(ReversiSquare::y)

    var y by property(y)
    fun yProperty() = getProperty(ReversiSquare::y)

    var highlight: Region by singleAssign()
    var highlightTransition: FadeTransition by singleAssign()

    val model = ReversiModel

    override val root = region {
        region {
            opacity = 0.0
            style = "-fx-border-width: 3; -fx-border-color: dodgerblue"
            highlight = this
        }
        // todo not sure this works with singleAssign
        highlightTransition = FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200.0), highlight).apply {
            fromValue = 0.0
            toValue = 1.0
        }

        styleProperty().bind(Bindings.`when`(model.legalMove(x, y))
                .then("-fx-background-color: derive(dodgerblue, -60%)")
                .otherwise("-fx-background-color: burlywood"))

        val light = Light.Distant().apply {
            azimuth = -135.0
            elevation = 30.0
        }
        effect = Lighting(light)
        setPrefSize(200.0,200.0)
        this += highlight
        addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET) {
            if(model.legalMove(x ,y).get()) {
                with(highlightTransition) {
                    rate =1.0
                    play()
                }
            }
        }
        addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET) {
            with(highlightTransition) {
                rate = -1.0
                play()
            }
        }
        onDoubleClick {
            model.play(x, y)
            highlightTransition.rate = -1.0
            highlightTransition.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by translating to TornadoFX, but writing the `layoutChildren` in Kotlin would look something like this:

```
override fun layoutChildren() {
    layoutInArea(highlight, 0.0, 0.0, width, height, baselineOffset, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
}
```

EDIT: You updated the code example to a View, so I think I understand what you want now :)

First, make sure the View doesn't require parameters, because that would make it impossible to inject this view. Either pass parameters using `by param()` or better yet, inject a ViewModel in the scope of the View, and inject that ViewModel into your View.

Maybe you can add x and y as properties to ReversiModel?

If you need to create a custom Region you can create what would be an anonymous inner class equivalent, in Java speak:

```
class ReversiSquare : View() {
    val model: ReversiModel by inject()

    override val root = object : Region() {
        // ...

        override fun layoutChildren() {
            layoutInArea(highlight, 0.0, 0.0, width, height, baselineOffset, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

To open this View now, create a new scope and push the ReversiModel into it:

```
// Create the model, set x, y and other initial state in the model
val model = ReversiModel()
model.x = 42

// Create a new scope and push the ReversiModel into it
val scope = Scope(model)

// Find the ReversiSquare in the new scope
find<ReversiSquare>(scope) {
    // Do something with the sequare, like openWindow() or similar
}
```

Comment: Sorry it is my questions that is bad. I want to know how to make this part of a TornadoFX view, i will post the code i have so far and the problem might be clearer.